# Should questions that are "Linked to" earn extra "Rep", á la "Street Cred"?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, duplicate-questions, linked-questions, cross-posting

Should a question that gets linked **to**...  "get a bump"... for it's ability to stand the test of time, answer most - if not all - there is to say on a topic, and that manifests itself as something that people ask, time, and time again?

At worst, it would create a "cheap" incentive to write more canonical questions.. with a best-case scenario being flocks of new OCD-sufferers - relentlessly dupe-checking and cross-referencing *ad nauseum*..

Maybe it could go both ways - as in - even though both the linking, and the linked to questions touched on the same overall "topic" - they both were allowed to exist independently...  and *both* deserve a few points?

Just an idea.

Comment: You don't mean automatic upvotes, do you?

Comment: No, automatic reputation for the OP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think any additional "bumping" is necessary.

A small amount of bumping happens naturally:

- people (hopefully) check if the linked-to question is indeed a duplicate,
- people who find (or asked!) the initial question look at the linked-to question for answers and
- those who link to the linked-to question might want to polish it a bit (I do that occasionally, as I don't like to "close as duplicate" of a badly phrased or ill-formatted question).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Jees, this is a *tough crowd*, lol.