# Reward linking questions

Tags: feature-request, reputation, linked-questions, incentive, organization

#### Reward linking questions to leverage and organize existing knowledge

There is already *so much knowledge* stored inside the Stack Exchange network. The chance is high that an answered question relates to a new one. And it will only increase:

The longer a knowledge domain is covered by SE, the more basic and simple questions will have been answered. Automatically new questions tend to become more niche and sophisticated over time. But they [don't pop out of thin air](https://www.everythingisaremix.info); they build upon established first principles and prior art. And when answered turn to part of that themselves.

In summary, the present knowledge will become always more important in relation to new questions and of course in general through its sheer extent.  To benefit users the most, it should be accessible in the easiest way possible. The web came up with [hyperlinks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperlink) for that, which have a special instance on SE as [linked questions](/q/1556).

To make the collective knowledge of SE more accessible, linked questions are the web's native, low barrier way. They create the eponymous navigatable web of wisdom and give context without search. There should be an incentive to create more of them to emphasize the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki) like character of the network.

---

#### How is this different from [Reward finding duplicate questions](/q/90620)?

This is another topic. Duplicate questions are *alternative phrasings* of an existing question. Linked questions are *other questions related to* an existing question.

The mechanisms, consequences and dynamics behind are completely different:

| Aspect | Linked question | Duplicate question |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Trigger | Answer/comment with [current site link](/a/280358) | Flag existing question |
| Appearance | List item on the right | Top center redirect |
| Relation | 1:n | 1:1 |
| Consequence | More context available, more interconnection | Question closed |
| Incentive dynamic | Depends on implementation | Built in [Fastest Gun in the West](/q/9731) |

Comment: See also: [It's time to reward the duplicate finders](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394048/8967612) on Meta Stack Overflow.

Comment: Another aspect is growth dynamics, allegorized in the balloon model: Learning knowledge is like an expanding balloon and its growing surface is new questions. There will always be more new questions, but still much more total knowledge: When enlarged, the volume of something grows faster than its surface. A consequence of this in biology is [Bergmann's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bergmann%27s_rule) or why penguins are larger at the South Pole than in Africa.

Comment: 1. Somewhat similar, except that the Rep goes to the Q linked to: '"[Should questions that are "Linked to" earn extra "Rep", á la "Street Cred"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106638/282094)"'. 2. Adding +1 to the dupe ***after*** a certain # of repetitions: "[Should duplicates add to the duplicated question's score?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146737/282094)". 3. The **most similar**: "[Can you get reputation when people follow links to questions or SO sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/128968/282094)", but again the benefit is directed at the other end of the link.

Answer (score 0):

I propose to reward 2 extra reputation when an answer or [comment](/q/296)* with a [linked question](/q/182014) receives an upvote, once per question.

**Conceptually not the comment but the act of linking is considered rewarded. It's only that the technical means to do it is via a comment.*

Comment: Nice idea, but it needs some form of quality control, and I think rewarding finders of good dupes has a higher priority.

Comment: Re *"...extra reputation ... receives an upvote"*: No, this goes against the principle that it is *always* users that (actively) award reputation points (by upvoting, approving suggested edits, bounties, etc.), not the system itself. This would cause too much inflation in the reputation point system.

Comment: The linking ***is*** very important, but mechanism for achieving it should be something else.

Comment: This would completely destabilize the current reputation system. Please don't.